# How to set default browser in Intellij products?

Tags: intellij-idea, browser, default

How can I set default browser in Intellij products? I know where to go in order to do that. File => Settings => Web Broswers => Default Browser. But I don`t know what I should write in the field with Default Browser. Should I write a path to the browser label or something alike?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you select the **Custom path** option, you have to specify the full path to the browser executable:

[image: custom path]

Sample path for Windows Chrome:

```
c:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
```

If you choose the **First listed** option, the first browser from the list will be used. Note that you can reorder the list using UP/DOWN arrows on the right tool bar.

In case the browser executable is present in the system `PATH` environment variable, you can specify just the executable name instead of the full path.